# How do I make an image stay at the bottom of the screen no matter the screen height/width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an image appear when you roll over text on the bottom right side of the screen. How do I get it down there for all screen widths and heights?

Comment: That's the thing. I don't know how to implement it...

Comment: Use position: fixed. That is the most convenient way of aligning elements to the viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll work:

```
<style type="text/css">
    img.floating {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
</style>
<img class="floating" src="url to image" />
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use fixed positioning on the image and assign the left,top, right or bottom attributes to suit your needs see: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp for an example

Comment: http://w3fools.com/ [MDN - positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/position)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Andrew, I'll refrain from using them in the future.

Answer (score 1):

`:hover` doesn't work for IE6 unless it's being used on a link. Use this.

```
<style type="text/css">
  #myFavoriteFooterImage {
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    position:fixed;
    display:none;
  }
</style>
<script type="javascript">
    document.getElementById("mousyTextFunTime").onmouseover = function(){
        document.getElementById("myFavoriteFooterImage").style.display = "";
    };
    document.getElementById("mousyTextFunTime").onmouseout = function(){
        document.getElementById("myFavoriteFooterImage").style.display = "none";
    };
</script>

<div id="mousyTextFunTime">Text to mouse over</div>
<img id="myFavoriteFooterImage" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSS style for :hover on the text.

```
<style type="text/css">
#bottom { display:none; }
#text:hover #bottom {
display:block;
position:absolute;
left:0; // how far from the left
bottom:0;
}
</style>
<div id="text>TEXT</div>
<img src="bottomimage.jpg" id="bottom">
```